# Problem about quotient abelian groups

Tags: abstract-algebra

Let $M$ and $N$ be normal subgroups of a group $G$ such that $G/M$ and $G/N$ are abelian. Show that $G/(M \cap N)$ is abelian. (Hint: Show that $f: G \rightarrow G/M \times G/N$, a \rightarrow(aM,aN) is a homomorphism. Determine its kernel and use the first Isomorphism Theorem).

First isomorphism theorem: Let $f : G \rightarrow H$ be a group homomorphism then $G/ker(f)$ is isomorphic to $im(f)$

Approach: Showing f is homomorphic is easy. $ker(f)=\{a| a \in M \cap N\}=M\cap N$

In this case we can conclude $G/M\cap N$ is isomorphic to $im(f)$, but I don't know how that helps us to show $G/(M \cap N)$ is abelian

Answer (score 1):

Let $f:G\rightarrow G/M\times G/N$ defined by $f(x)=([x]_M,[x]_N)$ where $[x]_M$ is the image of $x$ by the quotient map $G\rightarrow G/M$, $f(x)=(1_M,1_N)$ implies that $[x]=1_M, [x]=1_N$ this is equivalent to saying that $x\in M, x\in M$ i.e $x\in M\cap N$. We deduce that  $kerf= M\cap N$, the first isomorphism implies that $G/Ker f=G/M\cap N$ is isomorphic to a subgroup of $G/M\times G/N$,  since a subgroup of a commutative group is commutative we deduce that $G/M\cap N$ is commutative.

Comment: I just showed that. I am just wondering how that implies it's commutative

Comment: UMMM, so if $G/M$ is commutative and $G/N$ is commutative then $G/M \times G/N$ is commutative. You are gonna have to forgive me for my ignorance , but I am still cooking all these ideas. Can you explain why $G/M \times G/N$ is commutative?

Comment: $G/M$ commutative i.e  $x,y\in G/M, x.y=y.x$. Let $x,x'\in G/M, y,y'\in G/N. (x,y).(x',y')=(xx',yy')=(x'x,y'y)=(x',y').(x,y)$.